# How to programmatically check build.prop to verify model

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, adt

I have an app I'm currently working on based on the HTC Open Sense SDK for android. However my biggest problem is keeping up with the device checker through the Google Play dev console to only allow certain devices to download the app. My biggest reason is that people will rate my app so low on the scale and say it sucks, but the problem is that they don't read the requirements - if you use an Lg G2 to try and launch an app made for an HTC ONE that requires Sense, it's going to crash. 
So, how would i go about building a helper class that would check the device's model via build.prop (without needing root privileges) before opening/starting the main activity, and give the user a notification if the device was incapable of launching the app, and with devices that are capable of launching it, just continue the process of opening the app?